# CSS not applied to the HTML page (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

**index.html**
I have changed `{% static "/main/css/index.css" %}` to `{% static "main/css/index.css" %}`

```
 {% extends 'main/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{% static "/main/css/index.css" %}"/>
    {% block title %}
    {{title}}
    
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    
    <body>
      <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <header class="grid-header">
            <img class="circles" src="{% static "main/img/main8.jpg" %}" alt="main pic">
            <p>hello</p>
        </header>
      </div>
    </body>
    {% endblock %}
```

**index.css**

```
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1 fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1 fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'header header';
}

.circles {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "main/static"),
]
```

[image: file's location]

I tried changing file names, changing locations, connecting in a different way, but all this does not work. I also changed the settings.

Comment: Is the html file loading correctly (not including the stylesheet - just the html document)?

Comment: Also, please include any errors you see on your terminal and browser console.

Comment: @SeforaAbigail can you show your static folder structure?

Comment: Please open the css file url manually and update your question with the specific error message/http status. Please provide STATIC_ROOT value, INSTALLED_APPS list, urls.py contents, specific django version. Elaborate is DEBUG=true of false. Try running `collectstatic` and add all the command output to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS doesn't connect to HTML (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160835/css-doesnt-connect-to-html-django)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari yes! The question you are currently on has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of my configurations:

settings.py

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%load static%}
<html lang="en">
   <head>
```

My file structure is:

```
/Project
  /App
  /Project
    /settings.py
/static
  /styles.css
/templates
  /base.html
```

**You may need to share you directory structure to get further clarifications.**

Comment: /taskmanager 
//main
//static
///main
////css
/////index.css

Comment: Try going to http://127.0.0.1/static/main/css/index.css and see if you get a response